# File Search with specific Extension

Tags: c#

How can i search for files with particular extension, the search should be carried out through all the logical drives availbale in my computer.
i tried like

```
var di = new Directoryinfo(" somepath");  
Files = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

But my problem is search should carried out in Each and every folder.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();

foreach(var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    if(drive.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
        lst.Concat(Directory.GetFiles(drive.RootDirectory.FullName, "*.txt", 
                                      SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList());
}
```

**Note:** If you find files in all directories, it can give you `Access Denied error`.

Comment: I don't see `GetAllFiles` documented on the [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory) class in MSDN. Where is this defined?

Comment: Me neither, never heard of it - is it .NET1.1?

Comment: it's there in 3.5. And it is System.IO.Directory.GetFiles

Comment: OP asked for "all logical drives".

Comment: @oded my application is a wpf this is soem c# code am using in it. so that tag was by mistake. Sorry

Comment: @user1353565: I have edited my answer to include what you wanted.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal i tried with you code its taking only "C:\" no folder inside that. conside you have these files inside some folder ?? i dont think that code will work for that.

Comment: @user1353565: `SearchOption.AllDirectories` looks inside all directories. You sure you haven't used `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal some more things add with your example gave me a perfect result. Thank you

Comment: using System.IO; then show GetAllFiles documented on the Directory

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() contain an overload which has 'recursive/include subfolders'

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles.aspx

Looks like it!

Comment: OP asked for "all logical drives".

Comment: So enumerate the drives and use the above

Comment: @Charleh you mean i should use "EnumerateFiles" , i tried that also but not much help. Lets say i have some files saved under c:\user\mydocument\exp\exp\... , but when i search the way i mention its not locating those files at all..

Answer (score 0):

```
 Files = di.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Tried but result was the same . i want it to search in all folder and subfolders

Comment: OP asked for "all logical drives".